# Clearing Webstorms cache to resolve git issues on Mac Webstorm

Tags: git, webstorm

I often have issues like this in git when working on a mac when working with the git functionality in webstorm:

```
Error:error: pathspec 'addon/components/footer.js' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

However, using git in terminal does not have this issue.

What do I have to do to get webstorm to get back in sync with git?

To help narrow this down I see in the project view that one of the root folders is red coloured (exluded) when I have not marked this as so in `settings/project/directories`.

Comment: File/Invalidate caches, Restart is a usual way to clear WebStorm cache. But I'm not sure if it cures errors like yours

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue and I solved it by going to *Webstorm Preferences / Version Control / Git*
and then switch **SSH executable** to *Native*

after this change I could happily continue using git inside webstorm.

Btw this issue started happening after I've installed apple xcode. I had to accept xcode license because it broke my git path in webstorm saying something about requiring me to accept xcode license (yeah wtf). After I accepted it, webstorm got this issue...